# Is it possible to list all users in a TFS group from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am trying to recover some group membership information from an old TFS 2010 server for which the application tier is no longer available (but the SQL back-end has not yet been deleted). I know there are command line programs to get security information but I am wondering if it is possible to get security information (specifically group membership) given only the database tables/views.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you try to access the TFS database? What was the result?

Comment: @abatishchev I can access the TFS database but I honestly don't even know where to start looking. Under our TFS 2013 server the groups seem to be defined at a collection level so my first guess would be someplace in the database for that collection.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_Identity]`

Comment: When I run that SQL I get "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid object name 'Tfs_Configuration.dbo.tbl_Identity'."

Comment: Then use SQL Studio Management Studio to find the name of the table, filter by `identity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poking around and some trial-and-error, I found that the following SQL seems to work

```
USE MyCollection;

SELECT
   --grp.[SamAccountName] 'group_name',
    member.SamAccountName 'member_name'
FROM
    [ADObjects] grp
    JOIN ADObjectMemberships om ON om.ObjectSID = grp.ObjectSID
    JOIN ADObjects member ON om.MemberObjectSID = member.ObjectSID
WHERE
    grp.SamAccountName = 'MyGroup'
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a query I use to list all users and memberships within a TFS Collection.

```
Select    Object1.DisplayName as Name, 
          Object2.DisplayName as Membership
From      ADObjectMemberships Member1, 
          ADObjects Object1,
          ADObjects Object2
Where     Object1.ObjectSID = Member1.MemberObjectSID and
          Object2.ObjectSID = Member1.ObjectSID
Order By  Membership, Name
```